# When to use the Blazor Auto Interactivity Template?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I'm reading through the docs and resources and still don't understand when the *.Client project should be used, which comes with the template from `blazor -int Auto Example`.

So the Client project is a pure WebAssembly project, which, as I understood, is not the handy choice to read and write data securely from the backend. (It's possible, yes, but easier to protect when just choosing server projects for this task)

As I understood so far, the Client project seems to be the place to develop more or less static front pages "landing pages" instead of an interactive web app.

Comment: It's a confusing place. See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77613680/what-does-interactivity-location-mean-when-creating-a-blazor-app-from-a-templa

Comment: Maybe - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77768044/how-do-i-share-state-to-be-injected-across-components-rendered-in-different-rend

Comment: If you just want server select *InteractiveServer* with Global *Interactivity*.  InteractiveAuto is `InteractiveWebAssembly` with some extra confusing bits - which is why you have a client project.

Comment: Maybe - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77969941/is-there-no-blazor-server-app-template-anymore/77970043?noredirect=1#comment137460312_77970043

Comment: My question was not about how to create the different Blazor tastes, and more about if I understood the use case right

Comment: I'll answer your questions directly as you have given me a rebuke for pointing you to resources that might help your understanding. The answer to " if I understood the use case right" is no. and "the Client project seems to be the place to develop more or less static front pages "landing pages" instead of an interactive web app" - wrong.