Why is scoped service injected in MainLayout.razor reinstanced? on every page
I wanted to create a data store that was accessible between different pages on the site. On every page I want the same code to run. Rather than putting it on every page I figured it would be best to put it into MainLayout.razor so I can just edit it there in the one spot.
However each page has a new instance of the scoped data, and its not being shared.
If I take the code and manually insert it on each page then it works fine.
My questions are:

Why does this not work in MainLayout? Is it a different scope? Any other gotchas with this page?
What is the best way to have the same code run on every page without manually adding it?

This is a Server project (not WASM)
I tried:

in Program.cs :

builder.Services.AddScoped<ScopedDataStore>();


in MainLayout.razor:

@inject ScopedDataStore ScopedData
@inject NavigationManager _nav

...

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    ScopedData.SetCurrentUrl(_nav.Uri);
}


and ScopedDataStore:

public class ScopedDataStore
{

    private string CurrentUrl="";
    private string PreviousUrl="";

    public void SetCurrentUrl(string x)
    {
        PreviousUrl = CurrentUrl;
        CurrentUrl = x;
    }

    public string GetLastUrl()
    {
        return this.GetHashCode().ToString();
    }



}


This is in MainLayout.razor:
<article class="content px-4">
     

     @Body

     <h1>Last URL : @ScopedData.GetLastUrl()</h1

 </article>


EDIT:
To try and get around the issue I've created a component which I manually insert on each page - I can then edit the code in one spot:
@inject ScopedDataStore ScopedData
@inject NavigationManager _nav

<h3>Last URL = @(ScopedData.GetLastUrl()) </h3>
@code {

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        ScopedData.SetNavigationManager(_nav);
        Console.WriteLine("GlobalComp OnInitializedAsync");
        ScopedData.PushCurrentUrl(_nav.Uri);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

}


It's very important when asking questions about Blazor to describe what project type you're using.  I'm guessing it's a WASM project, right?  I'm curious-- how do you know that each page has a new instance?

Its a Server project (not wasm). The GetHashCode() returns a different number on each page, which I'm assuming means it's different. Also watching the real code as it runs, GetLastUrl should return PreviousUrl however it's always null, even though I can see SetCurrentUrl doing the right thing. Thanks for the tip, I'll edit the question to make it easier.

What RenderMode(s) are you using - and how are they scoped?

On the component pages I have @rendermode InteractiveServer and in Program.cs I have app.MapRazorComponents<App>().AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();.

So per Page/Component?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77613680/what-does-interactivity-location-mean-when-creating-a-blazor-app-from-a-templa

@MrCakaShaunCurtis - yes, its per Page/Component.


Why does this not work in MainLayout? Is it a different scope? Any other gotchas with this page?

The reason it's not being shared is because you have configured it that way.  Every navigation event is a round trip to the server because Route.Razor is statically rendered.
Layout is also statically rendered on the server in the HttpRequest context,  The page is rendered twice, once statically on the server and then a second time in the Blazor Hub SPA context.

What is the best way to have the same code run on every page without manually adding it?

Configure interactivity to global.
Change App.razor to:
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />

Read and understand - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0.
Updated Answer
You can't share a Scoped service between static and interactive pages.
Any Scoped service in a static page only exists for the lifetime of the the HttpRequest.  You can't get the last Url.
For the interactive pages you can either do as you've done and create a component or create a custom ComponentBase.
Here's how to do the custom ComponentBase.
I've added the code to SetParametersAsync rather than OnInitializedAsync because it then gets executed before any of the normal lifecycle code, and you are unlikely to override SetParametersAsync and forget to call base.
public class AppComponentBase : ComponentBase
{
    private bool _isInitialized;
    
    [Inject] protected NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; } = default!;
    [Inject] protected ScopedDataStore ScopedDataStore { get; set; } = default!;
    
    public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
        if (!_isInitialized)
        {
            this.ScopedDataStore.SetCurrentUrl(this.NavigationManager.Uri);
            _isInitialized = true;
        }
        return base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }
}

You can use this like:
@page "/"
@inherits AppComponentBase
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div class="alert alert-info m-2">@this.ScopedDataStore.GetLastUrl()</div>


Thanks for the suggestion. I made the changes you suggested - Indeed there is now only the one instance created, however in my global component which I've put in MainLayout after the @body statement, it doesn't have its OnInitializedAsync method called. I've edited the question and put the code in it.

Fixed an error - apparently my global component wasn't found but I didn't see any errors when compiling. My issue now is where should I put the code so that it's called on every page? I've tried OnInitializedAsync and OnAfterRender but these are not called on every page.

Managed to use the LocationChanged event of NavigationManager. Is there a better way?

Best solution depends on interactivity setting.  Have you switched to global?

Thanks for your help on this one. I ended up subscribing to the LocationChanged event in NavigationManager to detect page changes.
